# Wired connection stuck on connecting

Tags: networking, lubuntu, internet, ethernet

I recently installed Lubuntu alongside with Windows 7 on my computer, and I can't get the wired connection to work.

My machine is a Dell E5570 (Latitude 15) laptop with a Dell E-Port dock, when I connect the ethernet cable to the dock I see the following with `dmesg -Hw`:

```
[  +9,264007] e1000e: enp0s31f6 NIC Link is Up 100 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: None
[  +0,000007] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 enp0s31f6: 10/100 speed: disabling TSO
```

Then the status icon of internet is stuck on "connecting" (a little loop) and then one minute after I get the notification message "You are disconnected".

This is the output of `ifconfig`:

```
$ ifconfig 
enp0s20f0u7u2: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.42.252  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.42.255
    inet6 fe80::a945:4246:b6f5:d5e2  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 0e:04:ec:56:0a:27  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 14611  bytes 13392266 (13.3 MB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 12673  bytes 1831860 (1.8 MB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp0s31f6: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    ether 84:7b:eb:30:6b:eb  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 62  bytes 3968 (3.9 KB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 24  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 474  bytes 84105 (84.1 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
    device interrupt 16  memory 0xef200000-ef220000  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
    RX packets 2278  bytes 161681 (161.6 KB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 2278  bytes 161681 (161.6 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp1s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    ether e4:b3:18:0f:40:e7  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

`enp0s20...` is my phone connection.

Here is `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=false

[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

and `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

I can connect fine with Windows, I can connect to a wireless network with Ubuntu or even my phone shared connection through USB.

When I connect the cable directly to the computer it is not recognized: nothing is displayed in `dmesg` nor with the Network Manager.

I am behind a company proxy.

Have you got any idea on how to solve this problem?

Comment: What laptop model (and dock) you have ?

Comment: I added the `My machine is a Dell E5570 (Latitude 15) laptop with a Dell E-Port dock` part.

Comment: have you tried the ipv4 "link-local only" option?